# Calculate sum overlapping minutes in tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I have two excel extracts, one containing the schedules of employees and the other containing the actual times the employees worked. There are multiple schedule blocks in a day and employees can have multiple activity start and stop times in or out of scheduled time.

Schedule:

[image]

Actvtivity:

[image]

I need to use this data to calculate the sum of actual minutes worked only during the scheduled time with Tableau. In the above images the first schedule event would have 115 minutes worked and the second line would have 92 totaling in 207.

I tried to start easy by only calculating activity entries that fall within both the start and stop of a scheduled block, but tableau either return nothing or the "Many to 1" *

attempt 1:

```
case attr([#Fields:Date]) when ATTR([ScheduleStopStart].[#fields:excDate])
then
    if attr([Start]) >= Min([ScheduleStopStart].[Start])
    and attr([Stop]) <= max([ScheduleStopStart].[Stop])
    then datediff("minute", attr([Start]), attr([Stop]))
    END
END
```

Attempt 2:

```
IF ATTR([#Fields:Date]) = ATTR([ScheduleStopStart].[#fields:excDate]) then (
    if attr([Start]) >= attr([ScheduleStopStart].[Start])
    and attr([Stop]) <= attr([ScheduleStopStart].[Stop])
    then DATEDIFF("minute", attr([Start]),attr([Stop])) 
    else 0
    end 
)
else 
0
END
```

Comment: can you show output?

Comment: Hi Siva. The output I am getting from attempt 1 is blank and attempt 2 is 0